# How to add UITableView cell pagination with “peeking”?

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add something like what’s in the app store app:

[image]

As you can see, it isn’t just one cell that is paged, but you can also see the two edges of the cells from the left and right as well. I tried to implement this in my app by making each cell slightly smaller than the size of the collectionView, and then enabled isPagingEnabled, but when I flipped from cell to cell, it didn’t page from cell to cell, rather the width of the entire UICollectionView every time. This ended up in an unwanted effect where each page turned resulted in an increasing offset where cells were shifting further and further off the screen.

I researched a bit on this and implemented the targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset... but it was never called and didn’t work.

Preferably, I would want to keep the smooth behavior of the built-in pagination and just be able to tweak it.

Thanks!

Comment: What I would do is trigger the pagination api call 2 - 3 pages before so there are already items which I can scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing the peeking behavior yourself delegate it to a third party library [iCourasel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). Implementing it yourself you will ended up a `UICollectionView` inside of `UITableViewCell`. As of your requirement `iCarouselTypeLinear` suits your requirement.